# Iframe is blinking/refreshing while pressing button

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, iframe

I have a really strange problem. I use ASP.NET webform and i have a problem with IFRAME tag(pdf file inside). When i am pressing the button or selecting any item from dropdown, my iframe is refreshing/blinking, but it is still on the same page if you for example scrolled the pdf document.

[image]

[image]

```
<style>
    .myIframe {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 65.25%;
        padding-top: 30px;
        height: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        border: solid black 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .myIframe iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    @media (min-width: 1199.98px) {
        .myIframe iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 700px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .myIframe {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 65.25%;
            padding-top: 30px;
            height: 700px;
            overflow: auto;
            /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;*/
            border: solid black 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
</style>
            <div class="myIframe">
                <iframe id="iframepdf" src="Images/Collection 2018.pdf"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Check that , you have enabled the auto post back attribute in drop-down or button.Then try AutoPostBack="false"

Comment: @Manusha my drop-down doesn't work without post back